# Masking a pandas dataframe object

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, nan

I am trying to run the following code but I am getting the error message like 
"TypeError: The numpy boolean negative, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the `~` operator or the logical_not function instead."

I am getting the error when the line `np_mask = A_df_masked.notnull()` is runned.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

```
A_orig = np.array([[3, 4, 5, 2],
                   [4, 4, 3, 3],
                   [5, 5, 4, 4]], dtype=np.float32).T

A_orig_df = pd.DataFrame(A_orig)

#masking some of the entries
A_df_masked = A_orig_df.copy()
A_df_masked.iloc[0,0]=np.NAN

np_mask = A_df_masked.notnull()
```

The desired output of np_mask will be:

```
    0       1       2
0   False   True    True
1   True    True    True
2   True    True    True
3   True    True    True
```

Comment: What version of pandas and numpy are you using? I can't reproduce the error using the latest releases (numpy 1.13, pandas 0.20)

Comment: pandas (0.13.1),  numpy (1.13.1)

Comment: You should update pandas. I suspect the old version you have is using a deprecated feature of numpy.

Comment: I updated both packages and now I am getting the following error:

import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.io.html import read_html
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 25, in
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 57, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an incompatibility between older versions of Pandas and newer versions of NumPy (Reported in [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16751)) If you update pandas to a more recent version, the problem should be fixed.

Comment: I upgraded pandas to (0.21.0) version latest one. I still have the same issue now.

Comment: @mgokhanbakal Check if you changed your code by any chance. `np_mask.loc[0,0]` = False

Comment: I am using docker systems and I messed up to use the updated one. So, it is working now with the latest versions. Thanks for your help.